# Switch to tab 2 from a button on tab 1 using angular-mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am using angular material mat-tab content.

My code looks like -

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I want to implement something like

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
      <button mat-button>Go to tab 2</button>
      <button mat-button>Go to tab 3</button>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> 
      <button mat-button>Go to tab 1</button>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">
      <button mat-button>Go to tab 1</button>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

How to implement this functionality of on clicking on buttons it should go to different tabs?

Comment: Have a look at the docs, there's is an example with changing the tab differently: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples.

 I believe `<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="YourValue"
               (selectedIndexChange)=YourFunction($event)` solves your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use tab group template reference to change the selected index of the tab

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup>
  <mat-tab label="First">
     <button mat-button (click)="tabGroup.selectedIndex=1">Go to tab 2</button>
     <button mat-button (click)="tabGroup.selectedIndex=2">Go to tab 3</button>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> 
     <button mat-button (click)="tabGroup.selectedIndex=0">Go to tab 1</button>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">
     <button mat-button (click)="tabGroup.selectedIndex=0">Go to tab 1</button>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```